# Generate edges from an Arbitrary list of nodes

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

```
data Edge v = Edge {source :: v, target :: v}
          deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

data Graph v = Graph {nodes :: Set v, edges :: Set (Edge v)}
           deriving Show


instance Arbitrary v => Arbitrary (Edge v) where
    arbitrary = do s <- arbitrary
                   t <- arbitrary
                   return $ Edge {source = s, target = t}

instance (Ord v, Arbitrary v) => Arbitrary (Graph v) where
    arbitrary = aux `suchThat` validGraph
        where aux = do lNodes <- arbitrary
                       lEdges <- arbitrary
                       return $ Graph {nodes = fromList lNodes, edges = fromList lEdges}
```

I currently have this to generate my Graphs.
However by using sample on ghci I noticed that it either doesn't generate edges or it generates a single one.
Is it possible to control the number of edges generated?
How would I do it?

EDIT: A Graph is considered valid when: 
1-The source and target nodes of an edge exist.
2-A node can't be the source to more than one Edge.

Comment: it's probably really hard (you could say it's very *lucky*) to generate a `validGraph` like this (especially when there are more edges) - it's probably better to generate nodes and then draw pairs of nodes from those to generate edges

Comment: The thing is those pairs need to be generated arbitrarily. How do i tell haskell to form random pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:arbitrary) value is a value in the [`Gen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#t:Gen) monad. You can do more in this monad than just combine `arbitrary` values together. You can perform any of the other `Gen` operations including [`choose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:choose):

> ```
> choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a
> ```
>
> Generates a random element in the given inclusive range.

You can use `choose` to generate other random values than just `arbitrary` ones.

```
instance (Ord v, Arbitrary v) => Arbitrary (Graph v) where
    arbitrary = do
        nodes <- arbitrary
        let
            lNodes = toList nodes
            numNodes = length lNodes
            arbitraryEdge = do
                source <- elements lNodes
                target <- elements lNodes
                return $ Edge {
                    source = source,
                    target = target
                }
        numEdges <- choose (0, numNodes * numNodes)
        lEdges <- vectorOf numEdges arbitraryEdge
        return $ Graph {nodes = nodes, edges = fromList lEdges}
```

This naive implementation isn't very efficient when generating large graphs. It could be a factor of number of nodes in the graph faster if it didn't need to scan the list for the generated values each time it uses [`elements`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:elements)

Comment: I see. However this brings me to the same problem.. Either it doesn't generate edges or, if i do it with something similar to what you sent me, it does but not in a way that my graph would be considered valid...

Comment: btw, continuing with what i commented previously: if i do it with what you sent me it doesn't generate valid graphs because it keeps using repeated nodes as "source" to several Edges. A valid graph can't have a node that's source to more then one Edge.

Comment: @ohiohai That's not the criteria for being valid you specified in the question. If a node can't be the source to more than one edge you can generate 0 or 1 edges for each node instead of generating a bunch of arbitrary edges. It also suggests that your graph data type is wrong, since you could represent the graph as `Map k (Maybe k)` and have every graph always be valid.

Comment: Ah crap. Forgot to put both criteria in the question, sorry. Gonna edit it.